# Unwrapping atan vs. atan2

Tags: matlab, phase, unwrap

I can extract the phase of a complex number in Matlab using the `atan()` or `atan2()` functions.

`atan()` returns in interval limited to `[-pi/2,pi/2]`, and `atan2()` returns in interval limited to `[-pi,pi]`.

I want to see if I can unwrap the extracted phase in each case using the `unwrap()` function, but `unwrap` is only effective on phase extracted via `atan2()`.

```
R = 1; % Magnitude
theta = linspace(0,6*pi,100); % (radians) Angle array
theta_atan = zeros(1,length(theta)); % Prellocate for calculation 
theta_atan2 = zeros(1,length(theta)); % Prellocate for calculation
X = zeros(1,length(theta)); %Prelloc. 
Y = zeros(1,length(theta)); %Prelloc.   

for i = 1:length(theta)
    X(i) = R*cos(theta(i)); % Real part
    Y(i) = R*sin(theta(i)); % Imaginary part
    theta_atan(i) = atan(Y(i)/X(i)); 
    theta_atan2(i) = atan2(Y(i),X(i)); 
end
```

I plot the unwrapped extracted phase using each method:

```
figure(666)
plot(theta,unwrap(theta_atan));
hold on 
plot(theta,unwrap(theta_atan2));
legend('theta atan','theta atan2')
xlabel('input phase')
ylabel('extracted phase')
```

However, as you can see, unwrapping is only effective on the `atan2()` case. 
Even if I use `unwrap(theta_atan, pi/2)` (in this case unwrapping is based on increments of pi/2 instead of the default, pi), I fail to properly unwrap the `atan()` phase.

[image: Fig.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument to `unwrap` is not the period of the input data, but the tolerance. The function always unwraps data assuming a 2π interval. That is, it wants to see that `x(i)-x(i+1)` is larger than the tolerance before unwrapping, and smaller after unwrapping. In the case of a tolerance of `pi/2`, if, for example, `x(i)=0` and `x(i+1)=3`, the jump is larger than the tolerance, but adding or subtracting `2*pi` to `x(i+1)` does not improve things.

One work-around would be to multiply the input by 2, and divide by 2 after unwrapping:

```
unwrap(theta_atan * 2) / 2
```

However, it is always best to use `atan2` to obtain an angle.